# How to exclude a certain range in SQL results?

Tags: sql

I would like to copy a certain range within q SQL table and input into new table.  I also need to exclude part of the results.

I have seen on some forums and some SQL tutorial websites that they mostly use BETWEEN STATEMENT but this only can use in single condition.

My condition is copy the certain range with 2 conditions such as start copy with specific **part number** and end with **type** that is "A" but this data must be after ,so it can be a range.

**UPDATED**--
i am added 2 picture one is Table picture,another one is expected outcome.
condition will like get the data between part number is 1002 until the type is A.

Thanks All.

Table
[image: Table picture]

Expected Outcome
[image: Expected Outcome]

Comment: What is your SQL technology?  Post data table examples and data examples

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: @Brad i had updated the details,thanks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  i had updated the details,thanks

Comment: what are you ordering by `part`  or `no`.  Also are these the only two parts of type `A` or are there others with a higher `part` or `no`

Comment: @Hogan sry,what do you mean?

Comment: As I understand your question you want all the data "between" the rows that have a type of A.  in order for things to be between or before the data has to be ordered.  how are you ordering, what is the sort.  Also.  is there only two rows with type A or is there more that two rows with type A.  If there are more than two rows with type A then you also have to tell us what the criteria is for picking the starting A row and the ending A row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use and for multiple filters.

```
SELECT ...
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE CONDITION1 AND CONDITION2
```

For example

```
SELECT name
FROM People
WHERE age > 16 and home_town = 'New York City'
```

Comment: hi,thanks for reply,i had updated the question,thanks.

Comment: hi, can you help me have a look with the question?thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine multiple types conditions with your range.

Here we have simple "=" conditions, the use of BETWEEN and an exclusionary condition "<>".

```
SELECT ....
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE CONDITION1 = CRITERIA
    AND CONDITION2 = CRITERIA
    AND CONDITION3 = CRITERIA
    AND DATES_COLUMN BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-01
    AND CONDITION4 <> CRITERIA
GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME
```

Comment: hi,thanks for reply,i had updated the question,thanks.

Comment: hi, can you help me have a look with the question?thanks.